# Showing the simplifying steps of this equality ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please show me how these are equivalent in steps$$\frac{(h_2^2 - h_3^2 )}{\dfrac{1}{h_3}-\dfrac{1}{h_2}}=h_2 h_3 (h_2+h_3)$$ I thought it simplifies to $$(h_2^2-h_3^2)(h_3-h_2)$$This would be much appreciated, I cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: This is not a descriptive title, please change it.

Comment: It's not really necessary to include the actual inequality itself.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the numerator & the denominator by $h_2h_3\ne0,$

$$\frac{(h_2^2 - h_3^2 )}{\dfrac{1}{h_3}-\dfrac{1}{h_2}}= \frac{h_2h_3(h_2-h_3)(h_2+h_3)}{(h_2-h_3)}=h_2h_3(h_2+h_3)$$ assuming $h_2-h_3\ne0$

Comment: You can just safely assume that $h_2$ and $h_3$ is not $0$.

Comment: @InsigMath, that's what I have specified, but I need to assume $h_2\ne h_3$ which is clearly different from  $h_2h_3\ne0$

Comment: aa got it thanks.

Comment: Ahh okay, I understand.